# Is it possible to SignUp or Login with Parse Cloud Code using Swift?

Tags: javascript, swift, parse-platform

I wanted to share all my server code on Cloud Code to use it for Android and IOS. If I login or signup on Cloud Code, on Swift my PFUser.currentUser() is always nil. Is it possible to do this on Cloud code?

Comment: yes it is possible to sign up or login with cloud code. and plz show ur cloud code.